# Can't make Java created XML work with XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom

I'm creating an XML using DOM, I open the XML with explorer and it seems fine.
After that I created an XSL for it, add the reference to it programatically to the XML and boom, it works no longer.

I inspect the code in the browser and save the file as XML.
I open the XML with notepad++ and noticed the npp shows the XML file is encoded in "UCS-2 LE BOM" even though the XML header sais it's in "UTF-8", I don't know if this has to do with being saved from the browser or it's because of Java transformer.[File encoding according to npp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNOgF.png)

Anyway, I change the file encoding in npp to "UTF-8", open it again and it works flawlessly.
I've tried changing the transformer's encoding property `transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")` to different values but it will just change the XML header.
I googled around but I haven't found anything that's worked so far.

This is the code where the XML is created

```
    package modelo;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;


public class DAOXML {

    private static final String rutaUno = ".\\VerLibro.xml";
    private static final String rutaListado = ".\\listado.xml";


    public static boolean toXML(ArrayList<Libro> libros2) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        final String rutaActual = libros2.size()>1?rutaListado:rutaUno;


        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.newDocument();

            doc.setDocumentURI(rutaActual);
            doc.setXmlStandalone(true);

            Element libros = doc.createElement("libros");


            for(Libro l : libros2) {
                Element libro = doc.createElement("libro");
                Element isbn = doc.createElement("isbn");
                isbn.setTextContent(l.getISBN());
                libro.appendChild(isbn);
                Element editorial = doc.createElement("editorial_apellidos");
                editorial.setTextContent(l.getEditorial_apellidos());
                libro.appendChild(editorial);
                Element autor = doc.createElement("autor");
                autor.setTextContent(l.getAutor());
                libro.appendChild(autor);
                Element categoria = doc.createElement("categoria");
                categoria.setTextContent(l.getCategoria());
                libro.appendChild(categoria);
                Element titulo = doc.createElement("titulo");
                titulo.setTextContent(l.getTitulo());
                libro.appendChild(titulo);
                Element ubicacion = doc.createElement("ubicacion");
                ubicacion.setTextContent(l.getUbiacion());
                libro.appendChild(ubicacion);       
                libros.appendChild(libro);
            }
            doc.appendChild(libros);


            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        //  transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(rutaActual));
            //result.setWriter(new PrintWriter(new File(rutaActual), "UTF-8"));

            transformer.transform(source, result);

            if(rutaActual == rutaUno) {
                Node pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"VerLibro.xsl\"");
                doc.insertBefore(pi, libros);
            }
            else {
                Node pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"listado.xsl\"");
                doc.insertBefore(pi, libros);
            }


            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(rutaActual));

            return true;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

         } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer not immediately apparent to me. It would help to have the XML and XSL files and a full working example.

Comment: What are you attempting? To style or transform your XML? XSLT is a special purpose language to transform XML. Java like other general-purpose languages comes with an XSLT processor. Hence, you can directly apply xslt in code without inline reference in xml.

Comment: I want to show the XML data in a html table using XSLT, I have to make two separate files for XML and XSLT (it's a school assignment) but it may be a good idea to use the XSLT parser to create the file.

Comment: I'll add the XSLT code when I get home

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before you call `transform()`:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```